# Process value's form xml file into other xml file automatically

Tags: xml, html, server

so I have a question about processing XML files but I have exactly no clue where to start.

For a college assignment I have to make a HTML5 application which communicates with a 'thermostat'. To make this functional, the university provided me with an online XML file which operates as the thermostat. It has elements like the current time, current day, current temperature, etc., which change automatically. (the current day and time are generated to make 'time' go faster).

I wish to implement an overview of the past temperatures that the 'thermostat' has been on, by displaying graphs in the HTML5 document. To accomplish this I have already developed a line-chart which can get value's from another xml file.

To make this whole overview-page work, I will need a script that can parse value's from the first XML file (provided by my Uni), to the second XML file.

This has to work continuously. Even when the HTML5 page is closed.

I have access to a standard webserver, and thats it.

I was hoping anyone could help me with this or give me a clou where to start.

Part of the XML file provided by University:

```
<thermostat>
    <current_day>Tuesday</current_day>
    <time>16:32</time>
    <current_temperature>19.1</current_temperature>
</thermostat>
```

Part of the XML file I want to plot my graph from:

```
<chart>
    <point>
        <x>00:00</x>
        <y>17.0</y>
    </point>
    <point>
        <x>01:00</x>
        <y>18.0</y>
    </point>
    <point>
        <x>02:00</x>
        <y>17.0</y>
    </point>
    etc....
<chart>
```

I want the time and temperature from the first graph, every 15 seconds (which represents an hour in the server) to be transferred to the other xml file.